# Lifting module homomorphisms imposing conditions on characteristic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, modules, graded-rings-modules

Suppose that we are in the setting described in the first two paragraphs of [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123935/lifting-map-between-finitely-generated-modules). My question wants to deal with an instance of the study of the amount of freedom that the choice of the lifting $\hat{f}$ allows. In particular, I am interested in studying the relation between the characteristic polynomial $p\in A[t]$ of the original homomorphism $f$ and the corresponding characteristic polynomial $\hat{p}\in A[t]$ of the lifting $\hat{f}$. It is well known that under the described hypotheses $p$ divides $\hat{p}$ so we can write $\hat{p}=qp\in A[t]$ for some $q$. How general can this $q$ in relation to $p$ once the maps $\pi$ and $f$ have been fixed?

In particular, suppose that $A=\mathbb{R}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$, can we choose $q\in\mathbb{R}[t,x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$ interlacing the real roots of $p\in\mathbb{R}[t,x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$ for each evaluation of $(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})=(a_{1},\dots,a_{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$? That is, can we always choose the lifting $\hat{f}$ so that for all $(a_{1},\dots,a_{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have that $\lambda_{a,1}\leq\mu_{a,1}\leq\lambda_{a,2}\leq\dots\leq\lambda_{a,k-1}\leq\mu_{a,k-1}\leq\lambda_{a,k}$ with $\lambda_{a,i}$ the real roots of $p(t,a_{1},\dots,a_{n})$ and $\mu_{a,i}$ the real roots of $q(t,a_{1},\dots,a_{n})$?

If this is not always possible, what nontrivial conditions on $m$ or $f$ could guarantee this?

In general, I would appreciate results or recommendations of papers that deal with the relation between liftings of module homomorphisms and their corresponding characteristic polynomials.